# How to point a Bind to a control inside a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, datatemplate

I have a DataGrid with several DataTemplates for the columns. A column has a Button and another column has a TextBox . I need to focus the TextBox after the Button has been clicked (both elements are on the same row).

To manage the focus we normally use a Behavior on the Button but I need to pass to it the element to be focused. As it is inside a DataTemplate I'm not sure on how can I reference it from a Binding.

Any idea?